# How to make HTML/Javascript receive data from PHP script and display in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I know nothing about PHP. All I know is HTML. My question is how can I write JavaScript to receive data from PHP script and display the result in my HTML page?

For example,

```
<?php
include('lib/test.class.php');

$test = new Test();
$show = $test -> Try('Whatever ?whichever', 'xx', 'yy');

echo $show;
?>
```

How can I pass the value of "$show" and display the result inside an inline-block or something in a HTML page?

Comment: Do you have separate html and php page? Do you want to invoke php page at runtime using javascript and display that value? Please provide complete information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>The value of the variable is <?php echo $variable ?>.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity, PHP works on server side, meanwhile javascript is client side scripting language. That means PHP won't communicate directly with javascript, you need something that is called AJAX.

What you can do with PHP is to prepare the javascript code, let's assume you want to call the javascript function called Math.floor which is a real javascript function that accept a number. Also we suppose you would like to compute its parameter by some PHP function, suppose that function would be "count". You can write:

```
<script>
Match.floor(<?=count($_REQUEST); ?>);
</script>
```

Also i would point out that in case of string you should take into account the need of escaping the ' symbol.